# Tombstoning working, but does my app need it?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, codeplex, tombstoning

I am using the [Tombstone helper](http://tombstonehelper.codeplex.com/documentation?referringTitle=Home) from Codeplex and I am a bit confused, I thought that it saves the state of your app's controls i.e Textbox, and I use the code on one page of my app and don't use it on another page, but when I test it it just saves the state of the Textboxes in both pages the same, the Textbox without the Tombstone Helper attached when I test it keeps it's state.  The way I am testing is pressing the Windows logo on the emulator opening the browser and then keeping the back button pressed.

this is the code I am using for Tombstoning

```
protected override void OnNavigatingFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    this.SaveState(e); 
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    this.RestoreState();
}
```

I would appreciate if you could help me

Comment: Are you sure your testmethod actually causes thombstoning?

Comment: I don't know what other test methods I could do on an emulator

Comment: How long does it take for Tombstone to come into effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not actually tombstoning your app - only deactivating it. To force the app to tombstone (while debugging) do the following:

1. In Visual Studio, right-click the project in Solution Explorer and
   select **Properties** to open the Project Designer.
2. On the **Debug** tab, check the **Tombstone upon deactivation while
   debugging** check box if you want the application to tombstone when
   deactivated. Uncheck the check box if you want the application to go
   into a dormant state when deactivated.

source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402564(v=vs.92).aspx